# Update problem on terminal and Software Center on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: updates, software-center

`sudo apt-get update` and
`sudo apt-get upgrade` gives me this result

`E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?`

When I check Software Center it shows me 23 new updates available, but when I try to make update it never finish and all the time there is information about 23 new updates.

Comment: Ubuntu version?

Comment: Done. Solution found in a topic [http://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process]